# elasticsearch:java.lang.IllegalStateException: availableProcessors is already set to [12], rejecting [12]

Tags: elasticsearch

configuration:

`data:
    elasticsearch:
      cluster-name: DS_escluster
      cluster-nodes: 192.168.1.179:9300`

and the error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sensorDataAccessServiceImpl' defined in file [/usr/local/workspace/iots/iots-basic-data/target/classes/com/c503/iots/basic/data/access/service/impl/SensorDataAccessServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 5; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'elasticsearchServiceTemplate' defined in file [/usr/local/workspace/iots/iots-basic-data/target/classes/com/c503/iots/basic/data/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchServiceTemplate.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'elasticsearchClient' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient]: Factory method 'elasticsearchClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: availableProcessors is already set to [12], rejecting [12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:218) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1308) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1154) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:273) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1237) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1164) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
... 19 common frames omitted
```

What I've tried:

```
System.setProperty("es.set.netty.runtime.available.processors", "false");
```

there is really no error, but an empty project starts for 30s, and there will still be a warning message after five minutes, indicating that the node failed.(source http://programmersought.com/article/8040225496/;jsessionid=70FC7469589CCD7E8F7D10965C499E42)

What I should do?
Shoule I do something with my redis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to run a test,you may need a configuration like this

```
package com.c503.iots.basic.data.configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
@Configuration
public class ElasticsearchConfiguration {
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.setProperty("es.set.netty.runtime.available.processors", "false");
    }
}
```

and it dose not work for application;
if you want the application to run well,you can do this

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        System.setProperty("es.set.netty.runtime.available.processors", "false");
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
```

add the `System.setProperty("es.set.netty.runtime.available.processors", "false");` to the function main.

Comment: What does this mean, can you explain a bit?

Comment: @YuJiaao the two way to run test or main code if you have the same error

Comment: I mean why I need set `es.set.netty.runtime.available.processors` to `false`

Comment: you may need this blog  https://programmersought.com/article/8040225496/  @YuJiaao